# iOS10, Swift 3, and FCM delegate error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting error:

```
"Value of type FIRMessaging has no member 'remoteMessageDelegate'" on FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
```

I get this snippet code from FCM setup guide:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self //Get error on this line

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. It seems that Google documentation is out to date, I took a look [Cocoapods Firebase Messaging page](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseMessaging) and I solved updating the cocoapods repo doing inside the Terminal:

```
pod repo update
```

And then replacing the following lines in my Podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

With:

```
 pod 'Firebase', '~> 3.7'
 pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 1.2'
 pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '~> 3.3'
```

This will download FirebaseMessaging 1.2 instead of 1.1

Comment: I've been troubleshooting an issue related to FIRMessagingDelegate for about 5 hours now where it wouldn't let me assign the delegate to the AppDelegate.swift file and what solved it was setting a specific version of the pod with pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 1.2'  Thank you a ton!!

Answer (score 2):

Run in the console:

```
pod update
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your cocoapod version

try updating version of cocoapod to latest from terminal app

```
sudo gem update
```

After updating to latest cocoapod update your pods

```
pod update
```

Comment: This worked for me! Be patient when executing pod update. Took more than 5 minutes for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to update all pods you can just update those Firebase pods

As of CocoaPods 1.0, 'pod repo udpate' does not happen on 'pod install' by default

```
pod update 'Firebase/Core'
pod update 'Firebase/Database'
pod update 'Firebase/Auth'
pod update 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

Answer (score -1):

So you need to remove lines from podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

Then install pod, add these lines again and install again. This solved it for me.