# FCM + Swift 3 - Notifications not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know you've stumbled across this question before; several times in fact. But I have followed EVERY suggestion provided to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899712/fcm-background-notifications-not-working-in-ios), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753105/ios10-swift-3-and-fcm-delegate-error), and even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753105/ios10-swift-3-and-fcm-delegate-error).

(Written in Swift 3, running on Xcode 8.1)

Yes, my PUSH NOTIFICATIONS in Capabilities are on. And even my Background Modes Remote Capabilities is on - I've tried toggling the FirebaseAppDelegateProxy On and Off, checked the certificates (why, yes, it is pointing to the correct App bundle), moved the

```
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Cried, consumed copious amounts of sugar, prayed to God and then what ever other related deities I could think of, and still - naught.

It could just be a screaming need for a second set of eyes, but any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_,_ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                         selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                         name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                                         object: nil)

        return true
    }

    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    private func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
//        let tokenChars = deviceToken.bytes
        var tokenString = ""

        for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
            tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [[deviceToken.bytes as! CVarArg][i]])
        }

        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.unknown)

        print("tokenString: \(tokenString)")
    }
}
```

And here are the extensions...

```
import Foundation
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)

    }

}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

Tokens are logging into the console, FCM is connected, Cloud Messaging is holding my certificates... the only possible hint I MAY have is that Firebase Console doesn't count the one device it is sending a message to as being 'Sent'.

[image]
But the console looks fine.

```
2016-12-15 00:07:05.344 voltuser[4199:2008900] WARNING: Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
2016-12-15 00:07:05.349 voltuser[4199:2008900] Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-12-15 00:07:05.447 voltuser[4199] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2016-12-15 00:07:05.514: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
2016-12-15 00:07:05.520: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.2.0
2016-12-15 00:07:05.549 voltuser[4199:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3600000 started
2016-12-15 00:07:05.549 voltuser[4199:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see this)
2016-12-15 00:07:05.605 voltuser[4199] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000018] Already sending logs.
2016-12-15 00:07:05.679 voltuser[4199] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
2016-12-15 00:07:05.782 voltuser[4199] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
2016-12-15 00:07:05.824 voltuser[4199:] <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at here
2016-12-15 00:07:07.286 voltuser[4199:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
InstanceID token: c_4iSvTQcHw:APA91bGjKnPoH9LysKl9CQxCJRJsfqwXBSUFAmgRp-KEWKjWqe2j4nt6Y5gx8us41rB6eLnRCOwRntnbr_N1fh_swz8j-GvvChSsV3gvG8dufVFLpagdtOxrxPSgLubQrfw-JqkA-4wV
Connected to FCM.
And the snapshot says Snap (mx7zr3y6XpSGZ4uB4PhZ8QRHIvt2) <null>
[AnyHashable("notification"): {
    body = "THIS IS SO PAINFUL";
    e = 1;
    title = "WHY WONT YOU WORK";
}, AnyHashable("from"): 99570566728, AnyHashable("collapse_key"): com.mishastone.voltuser]
```

... but the message is logging just fine in my console. In fact, there are not outcrying errors at all!

*sigh*

My phone is not getting foreground, background or any sort of notification from the app - there's nothing. Zip. Zilch. Nada. Just the breaking sounds of my heart.

My iPhone is currently on 9.3.5. If that helps any.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - or suggestions for alternative push notification systems...

Comment: Are you sending the notification from Firebase Console or from your App Server? If from the App Server, can you add in a sample payload?

Comment: From the Firebase Console.

Comment: any luck with this? im currently also in the same boat

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out.
 p.s. im using Swift 3 syntax, you are missing the completionhandler in your willPresent method

> completionHandler
>   The block to execute with the presentation option for the notification. Always execute this block at some point during your implementation of this method.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as! [String: Any]



    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])

}
```

Comment: Ah, so that's what it was. I eventually fixed my error by just copying and pasting the example code over and over and over again. Thanks for pointing out the specifics of it!

Comment: Is this correct? The OP says "My iPhone is currently on 9.3.5.", yet this function (and the documentation you've linked to) says it's for SDK 10.0+

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about your code is perfect and still you are unable to receive FCM notifications then please update p12 certificate from Firebase console. You have to export only security key from Push certifcate and upload it . You will start receiving notifications.